# discord.js ReferenceError: member is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

can someone tell me why this is not working, it is working in another code but not this one......

Code:

```
channel.send(`@everyone ${member}`, BoosterEmbed)
```

Error:

```
channel.send(`${member}`, BoosterEmbed)
                ^
ReferenceError: member is not defined
```

Comment: Give more context. Show where you defined `member`.

Comment: oh fack forgot to do it lol

Comment: Can you show what you defined member as?

Comment: yes placed the whole code now

Answer (score 0):

Please note that as per the documentation for guildMemberUpdate is as follows and only includes two parameters:

```js
/**
* Emitted whenever a guild member changes - i.e. new role, removed role, nickname.
* Also emitted when the user's details (e.g. username) change.
* @event Client#guildMemberUpdate
* @param {GuildMember} oldMember The member before the update
* @param {GuildMember} newMember The member after the update
*/
```

You can find this here: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/client/actions/GuildMemberUpdate.js#L23

Please use `newMember` in place of `member` in your code. This should solve the issue you are facing.